# Is it possible to include the short caption of a figure/table in the marker text of the endfloat package?

Tags: endfloat

I would like to change the placeholder tag for my figures/tables produced by the `endfloat` package so that it also contains a short description or keyword (for example the shortcaption).

So instead of the marker text "Figure X about here", I would like to have something like "Figure X: Study Area, about here".

My figure layout is essentially as follows:

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering
\includegraphics{Images/StudyArea}
\caption[Short Caption]{Long Caption}
\label{fig:StudyArea}
\end{figure*}
```

I managed to change the marker text using:

```
\renewcommand\floatplace[1]{%
\begin{center}
[\csname #1name\endcsname~\csname thepost#1\endcsname\ about here.]
\end{center}}
```

And I know that I can get the short caption as a reference within my text with `\nameref{label}`.

But is it somehow possible to include this in the placeholder for all my figures/tables?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible straight-forward since the `endfloat` package writes the code lines of the figure contents to the file without scanning them, and therefore without knowledge of the `\caption` arguments. (In fact it does not even know if there is a `\caption` inside the figure at all.)

But you could introduce a helper macro to give `\floatplace` a hint right before every figure, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{endfloat}

% Command \setfloatcaption which defines \floatcaption
% which could be used later on in \floatplace
\newcommand\floatcaption{}
\newcommand\setfloatcaption[1]{%
  \renewcommand\floatcaption{#1}}

% Redefinition of \floatplace which uses \floatcaption
\renewcommand\floatplace[1]{%
  \begin{center}%
    [\csname #1name\endcsname~\csname thepost#1\endcsname: \floatcaption, about here.]
  \end{center}}

\begin{document}

\setfloatcaption{Study Area} % set \floatcaption used by \floatplace
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering
\includegraphics{Images/StudyArea}
\caption[Short Caption]{Long Caption}
\label{fig:StudyArea}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

results in "[Figure 1: Study Area, about here.]".